# PCA for sub-grouped dataset using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

One of our business case require us to run PCA algorithm for each **subgrouped** (in the below example -apple, orange) subset of data in our larger dataset i.e., we would like to run one PCA algo for the records whose **Type == Apple** and another PCA for the records whose **Type == Orange**.

Overall dataset typically contains around 5-6 Million records and have 100-200 features. The number of unique value in the **Type** column could be around 50K-60K.

We would like to run PCA algo per Type value in spark environment with python language. Please find the python code below where I could standardize the records and run PCA algo. However, the PCA algorithm ran for whole dataset using pyspark, instead of **subgrouped** dataset.

Currently, im stuck on implementing optimized verision PCA algo for **subgrouped** dataset. Any help or direction is much appreciated.

### Code

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
                        [("20181028","Apple",1,3,4,5),
                         ("20181029","Apple",10,2,6,7), 
                         ("20181128","Orange",12,19,7,16), 
                         ("20181129","Orange",9,7,3,5), 
                         ("20181120","Orange",6,3,4,5)],
                        ("Date", "Type","F1","F2","F3","F4")
                      )

df.show()

#Create vector
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["F1","F2","F3","F4"], outputCol="features")
VectorOutput = assembler.transform(df)

#standardize the input feature
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures",withStd=True, withMean=True)
scalerModel = scaler.fit(VectorOutput)
scaledData = scalerModel.transform(VectorOutput)

#Run PCA algo
pca = PCA(k=2, inputCol="scaledFeatures", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
model = pca.fit(scaledData)
result = model.transform(scaledData).select("Date","Type","pcaFeatures")

#Show the result
result.show(50,truncate=False)
```

### Output

```
+--------+------+---+---+---+---+
|    Date|  Type| F1| F2| F3| F4|
+--------+------+---+---+---+---+
|20181028| Apple|  1|  3|  4|  5|
|20181029| Apple| 10|  2|  6|  7|
|20181128|Orange| 12| 19|  7| 16|
|20181129|Orange|  9|  7|  3|  5|
|20181120|Orange|  6|  3|  4|  5|
+--------+------+---+---+---+---+

+--------+------+-----------------------------------------+
|Date    |Type  |pcaFeatures                              |
+--------+------+-----------------------------------------+
|20181028|Apple |[1.5045340541317065,-0.9528611894036658] |
|20181029|Apple |[-0.19719398621559137,0.6812534757461064]|
|20181128|Orange|[-2.9560149391613217,-0.3754979381651896]|
|20181129|Orange|[0.6717104866798362,0.5707559972381819]  |
|20181120|Orange|[0.9769643845653697,0.07634965458456777] |
+--------+------+-----------------------------------------+
```

### Update

I already have a python implementation of the existing case, where I will loop through each Type and build up the model. Below is my pseudo code of my implementation

```
foreach item in Type.Distinct()
  Filter the records corresponding to item
  Run PCA algorithm
  Append the result to output Dataset
```

However, I would like to implement in spark use its capability - such as partitioning the data, run pca such that multiple instance of pca run across various executor etc. Im also looking if there is any way to solve it using pair RDD's where key is the type and value is all the records belonging to particular type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Spark MlLib/Pipelines to build 1 model per each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640295/how-to-use-spark-mllib-pipelines-to-build-1-model-per-each-user)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I feel the answered mentioned in the link is the traditional way of resolving the issue, which doesnt require spark. I had the same implementation in python using the option 1 mentioned in the link. However, I would like to have per user ML model using spark capabilities - such as partitioning such that every record of an user belongs to one partition and parallel run the pca algorithm for each user

Comment: [Run ML algorithm inside map function in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428297/10465355) is probably more descriptive.